# What is the cause of an AABB error in Unity regarding Instantiated objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Edited:
[Image showing the error log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEBEA.png) So I have a script which identifies the list of items, removes the current ones and then re-spawns the original objects. This works 80 percent of the time but spits out an AABB error the other 20 and I don't know what the cause is. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share the complete error message.

Comment: and code too please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AABB is related to Bounding Box representing an axis aligned bounding box. Your AABB might not have proper alignment which is why you are receiving the error. There is a script that shows how your objects draw their bounding boxes so that you can set them up easily.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BoundingBox: MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (rend)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube(rend.bounds.center, rend.bounds.size);
        }
    }

//If your object is not within the bounding boundaries, then you can set your mesh up manually like this;

     void Start()
     {
       var meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
       meshFilter.mesh.bounds = new Bounds(transform.position, new Vector3(10, 5, 1));
     } 
}
```